# After performing string.slice() return string with part removed

Tags: ruby, string, slice

Im  sure this is very obvious but I cant seem to get it work.
I have a Pathname instance and Im attempting to remove the first directory from it and then return the rest of the string, but because slice returns the part removed it seems there is no way of getting the smaller string back.

```
filepath = Pathname.new("this_folder_needs_to_go/another_folder/file.html")
filedir = filepath.to_s.slice("this_folder_needs_to_go/")
newfilepath = filedir
```

I would hope `newfilepath` would be `another_folder/file.html` but instead it just returns `this_folder_needs_to_go/`

So how on earth to I get the string that has had the part removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split):

```
"this_folder_needs_to_go/another_folder/file.html".split('/', 2)[1]
# => "another_folder/file.html"
```

Comment: What if the path could vary in length every single time would that also work?

Comment: @SamMason, Yes, above expression split the string into two parts by `/`, and get the second part.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use .slice! instead of .slice if you're trying to modify your string

```
filepath = Pathname.new("this_folder_needs_to_go/another_folder/file.html")
filepath.to_s.slice!("this_folder_needs_to_go/")
puts filepath ==> "another_folder/file.html"
```

Though that will affect your filepath variable irreversibly.

Answer (score 0):

`#partition` will also work in a similar manner to `#split`

```
filepath = Pathname.new("this_folder_needs_to_go/another_folder/file.html")
file_dir = filepath.partition("this_folder_needs_to_go/")[-1]
file_dir
#=> "another_folder/file.html"
```

`#partition` returns [head,sep,tail] so this will look like `["","this_folder_needs_to_go","/another_folder/file.html"]` the `[-1]` says get the last element.